# Parse Text with "awk" and Modify One Of The Columns With "sed"

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a data seperated with pipe "|" and I would like to parse it with awk and write it into a DB.

```
EndpointRequest|ID-ip-172-31-70-119-eu-west-1-compute-internal-209879772|2022-05-12 08:20:03:467|0|ip-172-31-70-119|616e50193233020648|vfgh|GenericAmount|61d458303574b21f|Display|v1|Display-v1|PrepaidEndpoint|6227300ec1786d26|Corporate|62273041c8cf901071786d81|Health Line||||69.28.67.153|Java/1.8.0_321|application/xml|468|475|POST||http://127.0.0.1/endpoint/||200||2022-05-12 08:20:03:458|0|468|7|0|0|0|true|Http|null|null|HTTPConnector:CallPrepaid|Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2\nAuthorization: Bearer e3edbb1d8f5d8c828dc584ed293602bf\nContent-Type: application/xml\nX-Amzn-Trace-Id: Root=1-627cc333-7167\nX-Forwarded-For: XX.XX.XX.XX\nX-Forwarded-Port: 443\nX-Forwarded-Proto: https\n\n<?xml version="1.0"?>\n<!DOCTYPE cp_request SYSTEM "cp_req_websvr.dtd">\n<cp_request>\n    <cp_id>YY1880</cp_id>\n    <cp_transaction_id>SDP</cp_transaction_id>\n    <op_transaction_id>arr684754251</op_transaction_id>\n    <application>1</application>\n    <action>2</action>\n    <user_id type="MSISDN">9999999999</user_id>\n    <cp_timer>5</cp_timer>\n    <transaction_price>1900</transaction_price>\n    <transaction_currency>0</transaction_currency>\n</cp_request>
```

The data has many lines like the one above and I use the command below to get certain fields.

```
more file.log | egrep "EndpointRequest|EndpointSuccess|EndpointFailure" | egrep "PrepaidEndpoint" | awk -F"|" '{print $1"|"$2"|"$3"|"$4"|"$5"|"$12"|"$13"|"$15"|"$17"|"$21"|"$25"|"$30"|"$31"|"$32"|"$33"|"$44}'
```

The thing here is, on the last field (#44), there is an HTTP response that contains some headers and an XML payload. I need to get "op_transaction_id" value ("arr684754251") and add it to the end of the awk command, but am unable to do so. In a seperate command, I can get that value via "sed",

```
sed -n "s/.*<op_transaction_id>\(.*\)<\/op_transaction_id>.*/\1/p" file.log
```

How do I migrate the "sed" command into the "awk" command, so I can have "op_transaction_id" value as one of the fields in "awk".

Expected output:

```
EndpointRequest|ID-ip-172-31-70-119-eu-west-1-compute-internal-209879772|2022-05-12 08:20:03:467|0|ip-172-31-70-119|Display-v1|PrepaidEndpoint|Corporate|Health Line|69.28.67.153|475|200||2022-05-12 08:20:03:458|0|arr684754251
```

Thank you bash gurus. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your efforts; please do mention your expected output in your question to make question more clear, thank you.

Comment: Tangentially see also [useless use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) (you actually have a useless `more` but the same holds) and [useless use of `grep`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I migrate the "sed" command into the "awk" command

You might harness [`gensub` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html), consider following simple example, let `file.txt` be `|`-sheared with 3 columns:

```
<tag>text1</tag>|A|1
<tag>text2</tag>|B|2
<tag>text3</tag>|C|3
```

and say you want to get what is inside tag from 1st field and use `,` then you might do

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="|";OFS=","}{$1=gensub(/<tag>(.+)<\/tag>/,"\\1",1,$1);print}' file.txt
```

which gives output

```
text1,A,1
text2,B,2
text3,C,3
```

Arguments to `gensub` are regular expression, replacement, how (either number to point which occurence to replace or `"g"` for all) and target. `gensub` does return altered string, which we then assign as new value for 1st field. `FS` inform that field separator is `|` and `OFS` that output field separator is `,`. Note that you must **not** mindlessly copy your regular expression from `sed` to become 1st argument of `gensub`. For example `(` and `)` are used in GNU `sed` to denote literal brackets and needs to be escaped to get capturing group, in GNU `AWK` `(` and `)` denote capturing group and must be escaped to get literal brackets.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: Thanks Daweo. It worked like a charm. I also didn't need any text before or after the tags, so I added `.*` before the starting tag and after the closing tag. Like this `$44=gensub(/.*<op_transaction_id>(.+)<\/op_transaction_id>.*/,"\\1",1,$44)`